# how to find the file path from the open command

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I need to get the path of the file in  fo variable so that i can pass the path to the unzip_file function. how do i get the path here?

```
url = 'http://www.dtniq.com/product/mktsymbols_v2.zip'
open(url, 'r') do |fo|
  puts "unzipfile "
  unzip_file(fo, "c:\\temp11\\")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fo` in your block should be a [`Tempfile`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/classes/Tempfile.html) so you can use the [`path`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/classes/Tempfile.html#M004101) method:

```
url = 'http://www.dtniq.com/product/mktsymbols_v2.zip'
open(url, 'r') do |fo|
    puts "unzipfile "
    unzip_file(fo.path, "c:\\temp11\\")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

In terms of how to do it I would do this:

1. Find out the class of the object I am dealing with

   ```
   ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > tmp_file = open('tmp.txt', 'r')
     => #<File:tmp.txt> 
   ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > tmp_file.class
     => File
   ```
2. Go look up the documentation for that class

   Google Search : ruby file

   Which returns `Class: File ruby-doc.org` => www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html
3. Look at the methods. There is one called `path` -> looks interesting

If I haven't found an answer by now then

1. Continue looking around google/stack overflow for a bit
2. I really can't find a solution that matches my problem. Time to ask a question on here

Most of the time `1..3` should get you what you need. Once you learn to read the documentation you can do things a lot quicker. It's just trying to overcome how difficult it is to get into the docs when you first start.